# Need assistance with a SQL query involving multiple sorts

Tags: sql, sorting

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but my head starts to hurt when thinking about how to solve this. I've read on subqueries and PARTITION but I'm outside my knowledge. Here is a sample of my data:

```
TestID  StudentID   ComponentID Score
-------------------------------------
14919   3445    1   20
14919   3445    4   17
14919   3445    8   20
14919   3445    11  19
14919   3445    13  19
11339   3448    1   15
11339   3448    4   23
11339   3448    8   23
**11339 3448    11  22**
11339   3448    13  20
**14773 3448    1   20**
14773   3448    4   21
**14773 3448    8   23**
14773   3448    11  21
**14773 3448    13  21**
```

There can be multiple test attempts attached to the same `StudentID`. Attempts are noted by `TestID`.

I need to be able to query for the highest test score per `TestComponentID` over all attempts for each `StudentID`. There are only 5 component IDs. So for `StudentID = 14773`, between both `ComponentID` of 1, I just need the highest score. I would need the same for 4, 8, 11 and 13. I hope that makes sense. I highlighted the rows that would need to be returned. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the query I've attempted. It just returns the same number of rows as the original.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    sts.StudentStandardizedTestID, 
    sts.StandardizedTestComponentID, 
    sts.StudentID, 
    MAX(sts.score) OVER (PARTITION BY sts.StudentID) HIGHSCORE 
FROM 
    StandardizedTestScore sts
JOIN 
    StudentStandardizedTest sst ON sst.StudentStandardizedTestID = sts.StudentStandardizedTestID 
                                AND sst.standardizedtestid = 1
WHERE 
    sst.TranscriptSchoolID = 10
    AND sts.StandardizedTestComponentID = 1 
     OR sts.StandardizedTestComponentID = 4 
     OR sts.StandardizedTestComponentID = 8 
     OR sts.StandardizedTestComponentID = 11
     OR sts.StandardizedTestComponentID = 13 
ORDER BY 
    sts.studentid, sts.StandardizedTestComponentID
```

Comment: Is there anything that you've tried?

Comment: Yes, it won't let me post my query I've attempted here but I've tried using a PARTITION BY and I get the same number of rows as the original query. it's not only returning highest score for a particular component ID and Student ID.

Comment: If you tried to post a *screenshot* of the query, then yes, that may have been a problem.  But please post your query as *text*.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code to create your table and data.

```
CREATE TABLE StandardizedTestScore (`StudentStandardizedTestID` int(11) ,`studentid` int(11) ,`StandardizedTestComponentID` int(11),`score` int(11)); 
INSERT INTO StandardizedTestScore 
    (`TestID`, `studentid`, `componentid`, `score`)
VALUES
    (14919,3445,1,20),
    (14919,3445,4,17),
    (14919,3445,8,20),
    (14919,3445,11,19),
    (14919,3445,13,19),
    (11339,3448,1,15),
    (11339,3448,4,23),
    (11339,3448,8,23),
    (11339,3448,11,22),
    (11339,3448,13,20),
    (14773,3448,1,20),
    (14773,3448,4,21),
    (14773,3448,8,23),
    (14773,3448,11,21),
    (14773,3448,13,21);
```

The query you are looking for is this..

```
SELECT studentid,StandardizedTestComponentID as componentID,MAX(score) AS score  
FROM StandardizedTestScore 
GROUP BY studentid,StandardizedTestComponentID
```

The results are this..

```
studentid ComponentID Score
3445         1         20
3445         4         17
3445         8         20
3445        11         19
3445        13         19
3448         1         20
3448         4         23
3448         8         23
3448        11         22
3448        13         21
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. That was much simpler than I was trying to make it. So, is it the grouping that makes this work correctly?

Comment: In your case yes. You were thinking way to advance to solve a much simpler problem. Next time, you have questions like this, post the scripts to set up the example. A lot people won't take the time to make the demo, but if it was easy for them, you'll get a lot more responses, some probably better than mine. There are online sites where you can prepare the entire question like http://sqlfiddle.com/ and just provide a link to your test,  then people can quickly help you without too much effort on their part.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you need aggregation not sorting. Something like:

```
SELECT studentid,testid,componentid,MAX(score) AS score  
FROM yourtable  
GROUP BY studentid,testid,componentid
```

Comment: If I run this query, it still returns the same number of rows I had in the original dataset. Is there a way to JUST return high score f there are multiple Component IDs with one Student ID? In my data above, Student ID 3448 had 2 attempts. I need only the highest score for Component ID 1, 4, 8, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Remove testid from the select and group by clauses.  Then you will just have the highest score per student for each component regardless of testID.